# Preserve case sensitivity while convert schema in AWS schema conversion tool

Tags: aws-sct

I am converting my SQL server database schema to postgre sql schema using aws sct tool. However after running "Convert schema" option the scripts generated are case insensitive or have been converted to lower case.

Is there any rule or option that I can use to preserve the case sensitivity, which used to be Pascal case in sql server database.

Also, is there any other option to convert Pascal case to snake case while conversion from sql server to postgresql.